# Trigger to prevent update in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, cascade

I want to create a trigger which will prevent update in a row from that table if that entry is present in another table too.

example

```
Table M
m_id   title  
1       abc
2       def
3       ghi

Table N
n_id   m_id
1       2
2       3
```

so if try to update values 2 or 3 in table m it shouldn't allow that
whereas if i try to update value 1 from table it should do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to create a trigger `BEFORE UPDATE ON m FOR EACH ROW` that checks `IF OLD.m_id <> NEW.m_id AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM n WHERE n.m_id = OLD.m_id)` and throws an exception in that case.

Comment: Sorry for late reply but i already have a foreign key constraint what i want is that if i try to update the entry from table M which is present in table N then shouldn't allow me to do so.

Comment: can you give the final query if possible?